# how to call a redux saga generator function?

Tags: reactjs, redux, redux-saga

maybe im missing the point or how sagas work but I'm not sure how to do the following

```
export default function* (){
   yield all([
     takeLatest(TOGGLE_MODAL, toggleModal)
   ]);
}
```

I have this "initial" function and inside here I call other functions.
one of the functions I call is a generator function and it works correctly

```
function* myOtherFunction(){

}
```

say I want to call this function elsewhere in my code, how would I do it?
I want to call it inside an action creator

(it HAS to be a generator as I'm using `yield` inside it)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't call Sagas directly.
You create actions through action creators, which you then dispatch to the store.
You register your sagas in the saga middleware on your store, so they get called each time a specific action is received.

Let's say you have an action `CALL_OTHER_FUNCTION` and the corresponding action creator `callOtherFunction()`. you dispatch it somewhere, for example in an component with `mapDispatchToProps`:

```
const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => {
    return {
        callOtherFn: () => dispatch(callOtherFunction())
    };
```

};

In your saga, you now just have to listen to this action with `take()`, `takeAll()`, `takeLatest()` or another [effect creator](https://redux-saga.js.org/docs/api/) that suits your needs.

```
export default function* (){
   yield all([
     takeLatest(TOGGLE_MODAL, toggleModal),
     takeLatest(CALL_OTHER_FUNCTION, myOtherFunction]);
}
```

after that, your `myOtherFunction` generator is called on each action you dispatch to the store.